# WPF create style without overriding default style

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, resourcedictionary

In my wpf application I want to style all my TextBoxes. As a result my App.xaml looks like:

```
<Application x:Class="IM.WindowsApp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
        </Style>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

In MainWindow.xaml I have:

```
 <TextBox Text="Some Text" />
```

When I run that its great the text shows yellow just like I expected.

**Now here is my problem**

Now I want to add some **additional** style to that textbox. As a result I modify my code to look like

```
<TextBox Text="Some Text">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".8" />
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

When I run that my textbox foreground is not yellow any more :( . I do not want to replace the style.

**A solution will be to give the original style a resource key. Then I could place `BasedOn={StaticRecource MyResourceKey}`**. That is not a solution since I will have to add `Style="{StaticResource MyResourceKey}"` to all textboxes on my applicaiton. I will like to avoid doing that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can 'BasedOn' style without x:Key like this

```
<TextBox Text="Some Text" >
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".8" />
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
        </TextBox>
```

Comment: Did not worked :( . I though it was going to work seemed like a great solution.

Comment: Hmm.. This is vary strange. I created a new project for this and it works for me. Try to do this in empty project first, maybe you have another styles which override Foreground.

Comment: I created a base style `<Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}" x:Key="TxtInputBase" ... etc` then created `<Style TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TxtInputBase}" />` and doing that made your technique work. Thanks a lot! I do not understand why. Maybe I had to clean the solution it made no sense. Anyhow thanks again for the help works great.

Comment: Glad to hear that. What you did is the another way to make it works. I  hope you understand this: "By setting the x:Key property on a style, you are telling WPF that you only want to use this style when you explicitly reference it on a specific control.". So if you set x:Key="TxtInputBase" my solution will not work, because WPF will wait that you set style name explicitly.